# Increase Virtualbox 6.1 AV Performance for Win10 Guest / Run Win10 App un Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, sound, virtualbox, microphone

I literally have the hassle of dual-booting with Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04 because of ONE windows application that I need for an online course that I teach.  I pray for the day I can completely wipe out Windows on my boot and just boot Ubuntu, perhaps someone can help.

I installed the app in Ubuntu 18.04 via Virtualbox 6.1 with a Win10 guest. I also installed the relevant Virtualbox Extension Pack and downloaded all of the Win10 updates. The VDI file is 100 GB, twice the recommended size, I give it 4 out of 8 CPU cores and 4096 MB Base memory (while also closing all other open applications/windows on the Ubuntu 18.04 hosts).

Result:

Video works perfectly.  I just need to add it manually via the Vbox "Devices" after the starting the machine.  IF I try to enable it via VBox machine settings "USB Filter" the webcam will not be recognized and I still have to manually start it after I boot VBox into Win10. Annoying, but I can live with that, if it means I can delete Windows from my boot.

Audio simply will not work.

First, students couldn't hear me. Yes, I verified "Audio Input" was selected under Vbox "Devices" menu.

Secondly, when I emergency booted into Win10 to continue class, students oddly still could not hear me.  I literally had to run out and purchase an external mic.  It seems that Virtualbox 6.1 / & Extension Pack somehow negatively impacted my built-in microphone on my actually Win10 partition (bios?, driver issues? Don't know.)

Thirdly, now if I boot into Win10 and try to use my application without a mic, there is "feedback" noise only audible to students if I don't use my external mic. Even after re-boot problem persists.

I am not "in love" with virtualbox for obviously reasons.  I just need a 100% reliable solution to run my windows 10 application in Ubuntu with quality audio / video... All solutions welcome.

Comment: wine maybe or something

Comment: Spent the afternoon installing Wine 5.0... No luck.. I can install the app, easily.. the audio even works, but the video does not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with a USB mic. I've done well with the Blue Yeti mic in a Windows10 Guest Ubuntu 18.04 Host. Other cheaper mic options would probably work just as well.